# Same output for two entirely different queries

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

The following two queries gives the same output when run in R studio v_0.96

1)

```
ab<-sqldf('select a.Family_tree_id, a.parent_name
           from test as a, test as b 
           where a.child_id <> b.parent_id 
           group by a.Family_tree_id')
```

2)

```
cd<-sqldf('select a.Family_tree_id, a.parent_name
           from test as a
           where a.parent_name NOT IN 
           (select b.child_name from test as b)')
```

I don't seem to understand the reason behind the same answer though it seems the first one does an entirely different job than the second one. I am not very experienced in SQL so please bear with me. Is some more information about the dataset is required to answer this?

Comment: Please make this example reproducible by providing (a sample of) your data.

Answer (score 0):

Though, as asked by Paul, the dataset would come in handy there are several overlaps between the two queries:

- Both queries select people without children.
- DISTINCT is a sort of easy GROUP BY to prevent duplicates, your first query would have the same result if there is only one childless parent per family tree-id.

Also, in your second query, `, test as b` serves no purpose.

Comment: I knew that was your intention, but you already redefine b inside the `(select b.child_name from test as b)`. So the `, test as b` above that isn't needed.

Comment: My mistake - can't count queries!

Comment: i m sorry .. forgot to remove the "test as b" in the second query.. i do see now there is no use of it.. i m providing my sample dataset

Comment: It's ok, I would've expected an error that b was already defined (maybe). This isn't SQL Server so I'm not sure.

Comment: Family_tree_id child_id child_name parent_id parent_name
1 15764 Sherman_Miles 6574 Jason_Miles
1 6574 Jason_Miles 89657 Michael_Miles
1 89657 Michael_Miles 65428 William_Miles
2 98754 Robert_Jackson 35468 Michael_Jackson
2 35468 Michael_Jackson 65789 Jeremy_Jackson
2 65789 Jeremy_Jackson 3854 Randy_Jackson
2 3854 Randy_Jackson 69875 Marlon_Jackson
2 69875 Marlon_Jackson 325 Thomas_Jackson

Comment: every tuple has 5 attributes...its in a badly formatted way.. i m posting my first question here so dont know about formatting here much.. how can i post a table here?

Comment: @Bilalarif: You can (and should) add the example to your question. But I just tested your two queries on your sample data, and the results were different.

Comment: @Bilalarif: [Your query #1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c9d8/1) and [your query #2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c9d8/2).

Comment: @AndriyM strange. I am still getting same result i.e "1 William_miles 2 Thomas_Jackson" for both queries. Though I ran the equivalent of both queries in SAS 9.0 as a proc sql and i got different results. Wonder why only in R its giving this strange answer.

Comment: @Bilalarif: Basically, your first query doesn't seem to make much sense. You should try it without GROUP BY to see what I mean.